# Netty Scheduling

Tags: java, netty

I am using netty HexDumpProxy example(using Netty 5 lib),in that I want to send some messages to server for each 40 seconds. How to achieve this using Netty.
Help me to solve this.

Update:
here is my initChannel method,

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel sc) throws Exception {

        int readerIdleTimeSeconds = 5;
        int writerIdleTimeSeconds = 5;
        int allIdleTimeSeconds = 0;

        ChannelPipeline pipe = sc.pipeline();

//      pipe.addLast("rtspdecoder", new RtspRequestDecoder());
//      pipe.addLast("rtspencoder", new RtspResponseEncoder());

//      pipe.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
//      pipe.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
//      pipe.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());

//      pipe.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(readerIdleTimeSeconds, writerIdleTimeSeconds, allIdleTimeSeconds));
//      pipe.addLast("idleStateEventHandler", new MyIdlestaeEvtHandler());

        pipe.addLast("decoder", new MyRtspRequestDecoder());
        pipe.addLast("encoder", new MyRtspResponseEncoder());

        pipe.addLast("handler", new PServerRequestHandler(remoteHost, remotePort));

        pipe.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(readerIdleTimeSeconds, writerIdleTimeSeconds, allIdleTimeSeconds));
        pipe.addLast("idleStateEventHandler", new MyIdlestaeEvtHandler());
    }
```

here is MyIdlestaeEvtHandler class,

```
public class MyIdlestaeEvtHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {

        if(evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {

            IdleStateEvent e = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
            if(e.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                String s = "Ping Pong!";
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(s.getBytes()));
                System.err.println("writing idle------------------------");
            } else if(e.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
                System.err.println("reading idle------------------------");
                String s = "Pong Pong!";
                ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(s.getBytes()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to see the writing idle------------------------ but, the same is not passed to server, because I am not able to see this message in server debug messages.
Anything wrong with the code?

ThankYou

Comment: haven't you read the api?

Answer (score 1):

Netty 4.x provides the capability to schedule an instance of Runnable to be executed at a fixed rate using the scheduleAtFixedRate() method on a channel's eventloop.

[see javadoc for scheduleAtFixedRate() in EventExecutorGroup](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutorGroup.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Example:

```
  channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        System.out.println("print a line every 10 seconds with a 5 second initial delay");
      }
    }, 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IdleStateHandler. For more informations please check its javadocs.

Comment: The situation what I am working on, is like this,
I will use VLC as a client, HexdumpProxy as a mediator for controllChannel(only message transaction) and in another end, a streaming server.
When I will give rtsp url in vlc and click play, then the commands(messages) will be passed through this proxy code and then redirected to streaming server.
In proxy, I am parsing messages and I will mention destination ip address.So, streaming server will start streaming on this destination ip address, using rtp I will start play.

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is, vlc gives request, and in proxy, I am modifying the destionation ip address and sending to streaming server, and streaming server will start streaming to that IP.
So, vlc, the one who has initiated the request, will be idle, it will not receive any streams. Now I want to keep this VLC connection as well as streaming server connection live, to not invalidate the session by sending some messages to both streaming server  and vlc(one who has initiated the request).
For this, I need to send some messages to vlc as well as main server from proxy.

Comment: Using IdleStateHandler how to do this? can you show one example.

Comment: In this case, I have used the IdleStateHandler, and the request is coming inside the UserEvent handling module, and inside that
I am creating a String for constructing message, and I will create a ByteBuf from the string and writing to the outbound channel.
But the message is not passed to the streamin server as well as I am not getting any error messages in eclipse.

Comment: can you show me some example which is working with IdleStateHandler? I have tried but I am not able to understand where I am making mistake.